# ajax to submit php form to database, ajax part doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm very new to ajax so I followed a [tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-bootstrap-contact-form-using-php-and-ajax--cms-23068) but I can't get it to work. I tried search this forum for an answer but with no luck..

**HTML** (a bit stripped down from classes and bootstrap-stuff)

```
<form id="editUserForm" role="form">
  <input id="edit_employeenr" type="text" name="employeenr">
  <input id="edit_name" type="text" name="name">
  <select id="edit_membertype" name="membertype">
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Employee</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
<div id="editUserMsg">Successfully updated!</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#editUserMsg").hide();

  $("#editUserForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submitUserEdit();
  });

  function submitUserEdit(){
    var dataString = $("#editUserForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user_edit_process.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(text){
          if (text == "success"){
            userEditSuccess();
          }
        }
    });
  }

  function userEditSuccess(){
    $("#editUserMsg").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

**PHP** (user_edit_process.php)

```
<?php
  $employeenr = $_POST['employeenr'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $membertype = $_POST['membertype'];

  $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE users SET employeenr = ?, name = ?, membertype = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("isi", $employeenr, $name, $membertype);
  $stmt->execute();

  if ($stmt) {
    echo 'success';
  } else {
    echo 'fail';
  }
?>
```

if i put the `$("#editUserMsg").show().dealy(5000).fadeOut();` just above the `$.ajax` the message appears, so that must mean that the ajax code isn't working correct. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** Solved. I had forgotten to include the file where the variable `$link` wes defined.

Comment: <div id="editUserMsg> missing double quote

Comment: Only missed it here on the question, has double quote in the original code, thanks for notice! @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev

Comment: is it that **'s'** in `$s.ajax` also a typo?

Comment: yes it is! @ᴀʀᴛᴜʀғɪʟɪᴘɪᴀᴋ

Comment: Check the error from the ajax, just after the success parameter add this: 
   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); }

Comment: when I add that to my code it says, errorThrown is not defined @GhulamAli

Comment: error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); }

Comment: nothing at all happened @GhulamAli

Comment: Can you update your question with the error property?

Comment: that's the thing, I don't get any error... nothing happens. maybe I put it wrong? I placed it like this `success: function(text){ if (text == "success"){ userEditSuccess(); } },  error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus); }` ?

Comment: It's correct syntax. Check your Javascript console in browser.

Comment: the only error I get in my app.js (the file I have my js-codes in) is for a datepicker... @GhulamAli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111350/discussion-between-ghulam-ali-and-pixeldoris).

Comment: Reply to me on chat.

Comment: no need, the case is solved @GhulamAli

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: @GhulamAli when I decided to move the php-script to a new file, i forgot to include the file that defined the variable `$link`, felt so stupid when I realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem in your either in your prepare statement or in the bind_parameter. You should always check for error, so I suggest you do like this to check for errors:

```
<?php
    $employeenr = $_POST['employeenr'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $membertype = $_POST['membertype'];

    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET employeenr = ?, name = ?, membertype = ?"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    if (! $stmt->bind_param("isi", $employeenr, $name, $membertype)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
?>
```

and then in you JS, add this to your success method:

```
console.log(text);
```

Check your Firefox console (Ctrl-Shift-Q), and if there is an error you would find it under "Network" -> Click the "user_edit_process.php" in the list -> and in the right window under "Preview".

Comment: This solved the case, even tho I thought my PHP code were just fine. I moved the code to a different file and forgot to make the link to my database where I get the `$link` from, so that's why I wasn't able to create any connection. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is that all code that you have in *user_edit_process.php*?

Is the `$link` variable properly initialize?

You can try to comment part of your code in PHP file, and write something like below to test if you Ajax code work properly:

```
<?php
  $employeenr = $_POST['employeenr'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $membertype = $_POST['membertype'];

  // $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE users SET employeenr = ?, name = ?, membertype = ?");
  // $stmt->bind_param("isi", $employeenr, $name, $membertype);
  // $stmt->execute();

  if ($employeenr) {
    echo 'success';
  } else {
    echo 'fail';
  }
```

And then if you type something in first `employeenr` form input it should show **Successfully updated!**. If you leave this input empty and send form, it shouldn't show.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the PHP, it works like a charm if I use the `<form action="user_edit_process"....>` instead of using ajax. But I will still try this to make sure I haven't done anything with my PHP since last time it worked.

Comment: I changed the `if($stmt)` to `$employeenr` but still nothing. I'm using a server from our school for testing this, and I know that this server doesn't allow the `email($sendto, $message... etc)` maybe it blocks ajax?

Comment: And what about JavaScript console output in your browser?  Does it show some errors, when you dispaly your form and when you send it?